# Unchecked in between checkbox using shift key like gmail

Tags: jquery, html

Using following code I try to implement gmail like shift key functionality.

```js
var lastChecked = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $chkboxes = $('.chkbox');
  $chkboxes.click(function(e) {
    if (!lastChecked) {
      lastChecked = this;
      return;
    }

    if (e.shiftKey) {
      var start = $chkboxes.index(this);
      var end = $chkboxes.index(lastChecked);

      $chkboxes.slice(Math.min(start, end), Math.max(start, end) + 1).prop('checked', lastChecked.checked);

    }

    lastChecked = this;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="id_chk1" class="chkbox" value="1" />Check 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="id_chk2" class="chkbox" value="2" />Check 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="id_chk3" class="chkbox" value="3" />Check 3<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="id_chk4" class="chkbox" value="4" />Check 4<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="id_chk5" class="chkbox" value="5" />Check 5<br/>
```

But the problem is that if I select all the checkboxes and using shift key if I unchecked 3rd checkbox then its not unchecked 4th & 5th. This is working for gmail. Any alternative to this?

Comment: For those of us who don't use gmail much, could you update the question to explain what the shift key is supposed to do?

Comment: You're using `lastChecked.checked` as the state for the box that you shift-click on and all the boxes in between. So if you check boxes 1-5, then shift-click on 3, it will check boxes 3-5 because it's copying the state of 5, it won't uncheck them. Maybe you should be using `this.checked` instead of `lastChecked.checked`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this.checked` instead of `lastChecked.checked` when setting the `checked` property. So if you're unchecking a box with the shift key, it will uncheck all the other boxes, rather than copying the `checked` property of the previous checkbox.

```js
var lastChecked = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $chkboxes = $('.chkbox');
  $chkboxes.click(function(e) {
    if (!lastChecked) {
      lastChecked = this;
      return;
    }

    if (e.shiftKey) {
      var start = $chkboxes.index(this);
      var end = $chkboxes.index(lastChecked);

      $chkboxes.slice(Math.min(start, end), Math.max(start, end) + 1).prop('checked', this.checked);

    }

    lastChecked = this;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="id_chk1" class="chkbox" value="1" />Check 1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="id_chk2" class="chkbox" value="2" />Check 2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="id_chk3" class="chkbox" value="3" />Check 3<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="id_chk4" class="chkbox" value="4" />Check 4<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="id_chk5" class="chkbox" value="5" />Check 5<br/>
```

Comment: Yes you are right !! I should use this and not lastchecked.